# Developing a row extraction rule

Tags: r, function, group-by, dplyr

I want to develop a rule to extract certain rows from a matrix. I set up the example as follows:

```
mat1 = data.frame(matrix(nrow=508, ncol =5))
mat1[1:20,1] = rep(1,20)
mat1[1:20,2:5] = rnorm(20*4,0,1)
mat2 = data.frame(matrix(nrow=508, ncol =5))
seq1 <- seq(1,3,1)
mat2[1:27,1] = rep(seq1,9)
mat2[1:27,2:5] = rnorm(27*4,0,1)
mat3 = data.frame(matrix(nrow=508, ncol =5))
mat3[1:32,1] = rep(seq(1,4,1),8)
mat3[1:32,2:5] = rnorm(32*4,0,1)
colnames(mat1) = colnames(mat2) = colnames(mat3) = c("Cohort Number", "Alpha(t-1)", "date1", "date2", "date3")
mat.list <- list(mat1,mat2,mat3)
```

Example matrix

```
   Cohort Number  Alpha(t-1)      date1      date2       date3
1              1 -1.76745451 -1.3227308  2.7099501 -0.13797329
2              1 -0.72651808 -0.8714317  1.3200554  0.76964663
3              1 -0.50325892  0.0742336 -0.6460628  0.30148135
4              1  0.79592650  0.1353875 -0.5694022 -0.59019913
5              1  1.94064961  0.2255595  0.3156252 -0.90996475
6              1  0.27134932  0.3966957 -1.9198976  0.23998928
7              1 -1.13272507 -0.8603225 -1.2042036  0.06609958
8              1 -2.12392748  1.0905405 -0.3788234  0.92850110
9              1  0.22038996  0.4500683 -1.4617004  0.58498275
10             1  0.26348734 -0.8340913  1.2631368 -1.48490518
11             1  0.26931077 -0.5230622 -0.6615288  1.45668453
12             1 -2.03067695 -0.6432484  0.4801026  0.01808834
13             1  1.25915656 -0.1116544 -0.3004298 -1.04072722
14             1 -2.27894271 -2.1058424 -0.3351053 -1.04132045
15             1  0.47742052  2.1564274 -0.4733351 -0.53152019
16             1 -1.57680089 -0.1340645 -0.3134633  0.53223567
17             1  0.25245813 -0.8243152  0.5998211 -1.01892301
18             1  0.18391447 -1.3500645  1.6059798  1.43359399
19             1 -0.09602031  1.4921338 -0.6455687  0.66385823
20             1 -0.13613759  2.2474816  0.7311762 -2.46849071
mat2[1:27,]
   Cohort Number  Alpha(t-1)        date1       date2       date3
1              1 -0.76033920  1.317636591 -0.09684526 -0.08796725
2              2  0.05123185 -0.731591674 -0.37247406  0.04470346
3              3 -0.78460201  0.890336570  1.26737475 -0.39062992
4              1 -0.14111920  1.255008475 -0.32799815 -0.77277716
5              2 -0.46044451  1.175157970  0.82187906  0.54326905
6              3 -0.46804365  0.704203273 -2.04539007 -1.74782065
7              1  0.42009824  0.488807461  3.21093186 -0.13745029
8              2  1.27083389 -1.316989452  0.43565921  0.07870330
9              3 -0.16581119  1.872955624 -0.22399155 -0.79334562
10             1 -1.33436656  0.589311311 -1.03871415 -1.06221057
11             2  1.56584985  0.020699064  0.45691456  0.15858065
12             3  1.07756426 -0.045200151  0.05124461 -1.86633279
13             1 -1.01264994 -0.229406681  1.24954420  0.88846407
14             2 -0.09950713 -0.515798138  1.62560454 -0.20191909
15             3 -0.28319479  0.450854419  1.42963386 -1.11964154
16             1  0.51771608 -1.407248379  0.62626313  0.97775246
17             2 -0.43951262 -0.368739441  0.66564013 -0.79980882
18             3 -0.15865277 -0.231475146  0.37582330  0.93685867
19             1 -0.57758129  0.235550070  0.42480442 -0.14379249
20             2 -0.81726414 -1.207593079 -0.30000514  0.68967230
21             3 -0.72926703 -0.458849409  1.51162785  1.40921409
22             1 -0.32220454  0.334996561  1.26073381 -2.03405958
23             2 -0.51450039 -0.305634241  1.51021957  0.39775430
24             3  1.15476297 -1.040126709 -0.36192432 -0.37346894
25             1 -0.88053587 -0.006829769 -0.89855797 -0.39840858
26             2 -0.64435448  0.209561006 -0.13986834 -0.61308957
27             3  1.22492942  0.812693992 -1.32371617 -1.21852365

and 

> mat3[1:32,]
   Cohort Number Alpha(t-1)       date1       date2      date3
1              1 -0.7657871 -0.35390862 -0.23539987 -1.8365309
2              2 -0.6631690  1.36450837  0.78403072 -0.8344993
3              3 -1.0134022 -0.28380021  0.72149463 -0.7890273
4              4  2.6419455  0.26998803  2.03606725  0.8099134
5              1 -0.1383910  0.90845134  1.09273919  0.4651443
6              2 -0.7549340 -0.23185551  2.21119705 -0.1386960
7              3  0.7296121 -1.09145187 -1.18092505  0.1510642
8              4 -0.5583415  0.71988405  0.09454476 -0.8661514
9              1 -0.2420894 -0.03215026 -2.51249946  1.1659027
10             2 -0.6434337 -0.13910557 -1.10373674  1.2377968
11             3 -0.6297123  2.09797419  0.87128407 -0.1351845
12             4  0.6674166  0.48707847  0.36373509  1.0680623
13             1  0.6254708 -0.61311671  0.82542494  1.7320687
14             2 -2.4704173  0.98460064 -1.10416042  2.9627952
15             3 -0.2544887  0.63177246 -0.39138717  1.6942072
16             4 -0.9807623  1.11882794 -0.47669974  1.2383798
17             1 -0.6900549  1.68086482 -0.01405476 -1.3099288
18             2  1.4510505 -0.04752782  1.49735258  0.2963673
19             3 -1.1355194 -1.76263532 -1.49318214  1.3524114
20             4  0.7168833 -0.76833639  0.60752304 -1.0647885
21             1  2.0004745  2.13931057 -1.35036048 -0.7694501
22             2  2.0985591  0.01569677  0.33975952 -1.4979973
23             3  0.1703261 -1.47625208 -1.13228671  0.5686501
24             4  0.2632233 -0.55672667  0.33428217  0.5341078
25             1 -0.2741324 -1.61301237  0.78861248  0.4982554
26             2 -0.8793897 -1.07266362 -0.78158128  0.9127354
27             3  0.3920579 -0.59869834 -0.76775259  1.8137107
28             4 -1.4088488 -0.54954542  0.32421016  0.7284813
29             1 -1.2421837  0.50599077  1.62464999  0.6801672
30             2 -2.8980422  0.42197236  0.45243582  1.4939070
31             3  0.3965108 -1.35877353  1.52230797 -1.6552039
32             4  0.8112229  0.51970084  0.30830797 -2.0563928
```

What I want to do:

For every matrix in mat.list I want to extract 6 rows of data, according to certain criteria, and place these rows as a data.frame in a list labelled Output1. I want to store all remaining rows as a data.frame in Output2.

The process:

1) Group data by cohort number. 
2a. If there is 1 group (Cohort Number can only =  1). Move to column 2 and extract the 6 rows of matrix with the highest value for "Alpha(t-1)". Store these rows as a data.frame in a list named "Output1". Store all remaining rows as a data.frame in a list named "Output2".

2b. If there are 2 groups (Cohort number can = 1 or Cohort Number can =2) move to column 2 and extract the 3 rows with the largest "Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number ==1 and extract the 3 rows with largest"Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number == 2. Place the 6 rows extracted as a data.frame in a list named "Output1". Place all remaining rows as a data.frame in a list named "Output2".

2c. If there are 3 groups ("Cohort Number can = 1, Cohort Number can =2, Cohort Number can =3 ) move to column 2 and extract the 2 rows with the largest "Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number ==1, extract the 2 rows with the largest "Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number =2 and extract the 2 rows with the largest "Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number =3

2d. If there are 4 groups ("Cohort Number can = 1, Cohort Number can =2, Cohort Number can =3, Cohort Number = 4) move to column 2. Extract the 2 rows with the largest "Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number ==1. Extract the 2 row with the largest "Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number ==2. Extract the 1 row with the largest "Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number ==3 and Extract the 1 row with the largest "Alpha(t-1)" corresponding to Cohort Number ==4. Store the 6 key rows as a data.frame in Output1. Store all remaining rows as a data.frame in the list Output2.

Desired Output:

```
Output1 <- c()
Output2 <- c()
Output1[[1]] = mat1 %>% group_by(`Cohort Number`) %>% top_n(6, `Alpha(t-1)`)
Output1[[2]] = mat2 %>% group_by(`Cohort Number`) %>% top_n(2, `Alpha(t-1)`)

> Output1[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Cohort Number [1]
  `Cohort Number` `Alpha(t-1)`  date1  date2  date3
            <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1               1        0.796  0.135 -0.569 -0.590
2               1        1.94   0.226  0.316 -0.910
3               1        0.271  0.397 -1.92   0.240
4               1        0.269 -0.523 -0.662  1.46 
5               1        1.26  -0.112 -0.300 -1.04 
6               1        0.477  2.16  -0.473 -0.532
> Output1[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Cohort Number [3]
  `Cohort Number` `Alpha(t-1)`   date1  date2   date3
            <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1               1        0.420  0.489   3.21  -0.137 
2               2        1.27  -1.32    0.436  0.0787
3               2        1.57   0.0207  0.457  0.159 
4               1        0.518 -1.41    0.626  0.978 
5               3        1.15  -1.04   -0.362 -0.373 
6               3        1.22   0.813  -1.32  -1.22
```

Overall I need a function to do this because i have over 1000 matrices in my actual application and can't do this manually.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to create Output2[[1]] and Output2[[2]] respectively as examples. However I think the idea should be clear. Output2[[1]] should consist of all rows not include in Output1[[1]] from Mat1. Output2[[2]] should consist of all rows not included in Output1[[2]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can count the number of distinct values in `Cohort Number` and based on that select the value of `n` in `top_n`. For distinct values which are more than 3, we create vector of values to select in `top_n` for each `Cohort Number`.

```
library(tidyverse)

output1 <- map(mat.list, function(x) {
   dist <- n_distinct(x$`Cohort Number`, na.rm = TRUE)
   if(dist <= 3)
     x %>%
       group_by(`Cohort Number`) %>%
       top_n(6/dist, `Alpha(t-1)`)
    else 
      map2_df(list(2, 2, 1, 1),x %>% na.omit %>% group_split(`Cohort Number`), 
               ~.y %>% top_n(.x, `Alpha(t-1)`))
})
```

and for `output2`, we use `map2` with `ant_join`

```
output2 <- map2(mat.list, output1, anti_join)
```

Confirming the output

```
map_dbl(output1, nrow)
#[1] 6 6 6

map_dbl(output2, nrow)
#[1] 502 502 502
```